# get everything from stringstream

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stringstream

I have placed som information to stringstream ss:

```
stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
ss<<"abc 456 ";
ss<<123
```

Then I decided to retrieve string content to string g:

```
std::string s;
std::string g;

for (int n=0; n<c; n++)
{
ss >> s;
g=g+s;
}
cout << g <<endl;
```

For this reason I need to know how many placements was done to ss. How to know that? Probably method that retrieves string information is not very clever - then give your way.

Comment: to expand slightly on the above comment: string g = ss.str();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to know how many placements was done to ss. How to know that?

You'll need to count this yourself, stringstream provides no ability to count how many insertions were done to it.

> Probably method that retrieves string information is not very clever - then give your way.

How about:

```
ss.str()
```

To get the full string with everything thats been inserted into it.

Comment: or use string objects and use c_str() to convert back if the situation allows :)